# Odd screen tinting when touching sections of web app on iPad

Tags: ipad, mobile, touch, tint

I have this odd behavior happening when a user touches any part of our web application. The interface consists of an iframe that has two nested iframes. When any part of the iframe is touched, the entire section tints or dims? The tint/dim goes away when not touching. It is very similar to standard iOS "Copy" behavior, just that there is never a "Copy" option. Does anyone have an idea as to what may be causing this?

I have added during touch image plus a link to a video illustrating the problem.

**During Touch Image**: http://www.smartertools.com/images/misc/img_0599.jpg

**Video**: http://www.smartertools.com/images/misc/img_0597.mov

Comment: Problem solved...and it was simple, so simple its slightly embarrassing to mention. There is a css property specific to webkit called "-webkit-tap-highlight-color".

Comment: I find it helpful to do `* { -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0); }`